# Thermodynamics - Change in temperature based on time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-conductivity

Hello Physics Stack Exchange,

This is my first post on this forum, please correct me on any semantic mistakes I may make.

Recently in my physics class we did a lab on Heat Capacity, where we had a 250g iron weight (at room temperature) and a beaker with 300ml of water heated to approximately 100°C . The goal of the lab was to log the change in temperature of the water once the room temperature iron weight was placed into the beaker of water. We were to stop logging temperature when the drop became stagnant.

However, the beaker was insulated and we could not see inside it. As a result we didn't notice that the thermal probe was not in the water, therefore all our results were invalid.

My question to you: I'm writing a simulation to try and re-create valid data for our lab, assuming there are a lot of "perfect" values (such as the beaker was perfectly insulated) how would I calculate the change in temperature based on time?

I've seen this post [on a similar subject](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24443/calculating-temperature-of-water-in-the-freezer) however the equation presented in the solution does not make sense to me, and I'm not sure if I can apply it to my scenario.

EDIT: Simulating my data will not achieve me a better mark, as the data is only required for calculations. The data needs to match the lab's criteria, but the data accuracy will not influence my grade.

Comment: Do the lab again, and get good data.

Comment: Not an option. We only had one chance to do the lab. I'm looking for a mathematical solution at this point.

Comment: Simulations don't create data. They create the fiction that you know what you were doing when in reality all you did was to mess up. The only thing that you can learn here is that sometimes it's hard to be honest, but in the long term it will pay off. Or you can chose to become a sophisticated liar, which, at the end of the day, is still just a liar.

Comment: I reread that comment a few times, and I understand your point. Real world observations would be nice, however if I included the simulated data I would mark it as a "simulation" not "reality"

Comment: Welcome to Physics .SE! I agree with the others. You cannot simulate  the lab and then pretend you got genuine data. Perhaps you could ask the professor if it would be acceptable to simulate the experiment and compare your results with the rest of the class. By the way: how much water did you have? I guess 300 ml (not Ml), right?

Comment: It is millilitres, and the data will not be compared to what the class got. The labs data are evaluated based on the individual, and the data is solely needed for calculations based off of them. I won't get a better grade if my observations are more accurate then everybody else's. I need this purely for calculations.

Comment: No solution I'm assuming?

Comment: Can one simulate this system? Sure, but what's the point? If all you need is good data, ask another student who did the same experiment and who has good data to give you theirs. Tell the professor that you messed up with the experiment, use the other student's data (with acknowledgement of the source) and show that you can do the calculations and error estimates.

Comment: At this point coming to a conclusion seems less of a trivial matter, but more of an ethical one. 

I cannot copy data off of another group, as the teacher would assume I copied their entire lab.

At this point, a solution would be a great help.

Comment: Talk to your teacher, explain what happened, and ask him or her what acceptable options would be.    Don't guess what he or she might accept.  Borrowing someone else's data might be perfectly ok, but a simulation not.  Or vice versa.  You won't know unless you ask!

Comment: I've talked to the teacher and he told me that my data is only used for calculations, therefore simulating it is perfectly fine. Does somebody here know thermodynamics, and can give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will require the specific heat capacity values of water, beaker and iron assuming what you used in the lab was pure iron weight. these are usually available online. now principle of calorimetry tells us that assuming no heat is lost to the surroundings heat lost by the hot body is equal to heat gained by the cold body. let room temperature be T(r) and final temperature reached be T(f).

Now heat lost by water= mass of water * S(w) * (100-T(f)).
    heat lost by beaker=mass of beaker * S(b) * (100-T(f)).

here T(f) is expressed in celsius and S(w) is specific heat capacity of water, etc.
Equate this to heat gained by the iron

heat gained= mass of iron * S(Fe) * (T(f)-T(r))

Solve for T(f).